# how to check if date is 3 months older in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a date in this variable

```
$start_date = '2021-03-04';
```

I want to check if this date is three months older than current date How i can check that

```
if($start_date < 3 months ???)
{

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use `strtotime('-3 month')` to get the timestamp for 3 months ago from the current date.

Comment: Have you tried to put "php subtract 3 month from date" into the search engine of your choice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Carbon`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) to achive this:

```
$start_date = new Carbon\Carbon('2021-03-04');
if($start_date->diffInMonths() > 3)
{

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `>` to check if it's _older_ than 3 months?

Comment: Oh, right \*facepalm\* Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You need something similar to:

```
$format = "y-m-d";
$start_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $start_date);
$end_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $start_date);
$end_date = $end_date->modify('+3 month');
if($start_date < $end_date)
{

}
```

I haven't tested the code, but you can get an idea.

Comment: The if condition would always be true since you are adding the months from the startdate. but the idea is good

Comment: @bitfroster You can do `clone $start_date->modify('+3 month')` to prevent this

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
$start_date = '2021-03-04';

if($start_date < date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 months'))){
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon for that.

```
        // parse your date as carbon date & only take the date string using toDateString
        $start_date = Carbon::parse('2021-03-04')->toDateString();

        // take the Today time, subtract 3 months from it & only take date string from it
        $today = Carbon::today()->subMonths(3)->toDateString();
        if ($start_date < $today) {
            // whatever you wanna do here
        }
```

Note: Carbon adds timestamp so using `toDateString()` you ignore that timestamp & only factor in the date string